# Ключ кэша для динамических данных

Tags: php, кэширование, redis

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется страница оформления заказа, где подключен агрегатор доставок - X. В "X" необходимо по API отправлять потоварно габариты, вес, а так же адрес. После чего "X" думает от 2 до 10 секунд и отдает нам ответ. На странице доступно несколько вариантов доставки и когда пользователь переключается с "X" на другой, а потом обратно, то снова ожидание 2-10сек, что очень долго и критично для бизнеса.

Решили закэшировать результат агрегатора "Х", но вот столкнулись с проблемой, а что брать за ключ кэша.

Мое предположение, что можно использовать строку "Адрес-ID Товара-Количество-Габариты-Вес" как ключ, но хотелось бы услышать мнение со стороны. Возможны ваши кейсы по решению похожих ситуаций.

Comment: Вообще 2-10 секунд это очень долго. Почему агрегатор сам не кэширует такие данные и вообще так долго работает? По-хорошему на его стороне нужно проблему решать.

Comment: Я с вами согласен полностью, но к сожалению они ничего не кэшируют.

Comment: Ну, возможно известны какие-то границы, в которых аггрегатор что-то считает, как он округляет вес и т.д., тогда можно кэшировать с этим округлением. Если кэшировать с точностью до граммов и единиц товара, боюсь, толку будет мало. Разве что когда один пользователь туда-сюда будет пробовать переключать, от кэша будет какой-то толк.

Comment: Нам и важно закэшировать хотя бы для одного пользователя. 
Просто такой огромный ключ для кэша у меня вызывает сомнения в правильности этого решения.

Comment: Ну а какие у вас ещё варианты, если от всех этих параметров значение зависит.

Comment: Используйте в качестве ключа для кэша кэш от вашей строки, например, md5.

Comment: @ВикторКарев Хорошая мысль, хотя могут быть и коллизии